# Binding a button to a model

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have bound a checkbox (output from options data in a loop):

```html
<input type="checkbox" v-model="option.active">
```

```javascript
options: [
    {
        name: 'one',
        active: false,
    },
    {
        name: 'two',
        active: false,
    },
    ....
]
```

I also want a button to be able to turn off the checkbox.

How can I also bind a button to the model?

Comment: `<button @click="option.active = false">Click</button>`

Comment: Thanks - anyway to move that to a method?

Comment: Yes, there is. Take a look at the [Vue documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) and then maybe post a separate question if there is something specific that you don't understand about how event handling works in Vue.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to pass data to methods, but passing option.active will just pass true, how to I pass the reference to the option.active in the data object?

Comment: Pass `option` as the param and then in the method: `option.active = false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the click event of the button:

```html
<button v-on:click="option.active = false">Click</button>
```

or

```html
<button @click="option.active = false">Click</button>
```